# MySQL - Can we order by column position instead of name?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've looked on Google but couldn't find it. Can we order in MySQL using field's position ?

Let's say I got fields `ID | FirstName | LastName | Age` but I want to order by field 4, could I do something like `ORDER BY FieldPos4` to order on Age ? I have not manage to find something about that.

Thanks.

Comment: I typed this into google `order by column position in mysql` and it was the first link provided.

Comment: Why would you want to be unspecific regarding what column to order your sql results by? When passing a query in MySQL, you should try to avoin willy-nilly requests, so you should specify the column name to order it by.

Comment: i think it is especially useful to go that way if you have some complex expressions, maybe without alias?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can refer to the columns by position (1-based):

```
ORDER BY 4
```

From [**the documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#id756773) (emphasis mine):

> Columns selected for output can be referred to in ORDER BY and GROUP
>   BY clauses using column names, column aliases, or **column positions.
>   Column positions are integers and begin with 1**

Comment: However the same documentation states: Use of column positions is deprecated because the syntax has been removed from the SQL standard.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of one advantage for sorting the columns by position instead of their names as it will save you time if you are using the same columns for sorting repeatedly so you can instead use the positions.

The disadvantages are:

1. It increases the chances that you might make a mistake while mentioning the column position.
2. If the column doesn't exist in the select list but the column position does, the list will get sorted but not by the column you wanted but by the position you have mentioned and you might have to spend a lot of time figuring this out because it won't throw an error like it would if you were to mention the column name.